# My site is asking for age verfication?

Tags: html, mobile, meta, restriction

This is a duplicate of: [This question without any answerers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11971190/why-is-my-site-asking-for-age-verification-on-a-smart-phone-when-there-is-no-age) Just so you're aware.

**Details**

So my site is a game site with questions. These questions contain swear words. This is not an adult site. It should not be listed as an adult site imo.

**Problem**
If you try to access this site from your mobile network it will ask for age verification. Is there some way to change how your site is listed?

**Solution?**

Is there maybe some meta tag I can put into the site to notify the browser or carrier that this isn't an adult site?

Comment: Why not take out the swear words? Think like a parent...

Comment: can't do that, the questions are user submitted. Its kind of integral to the site :)

Comment: Well, that's an important detail that you left out :)

Comment: oppies :p you still have to go past a portal. The opening is disgusting would you rathers or lovely would you rathers.. So there aren't any swear words unless you say yes please. But you have given me something to think about

Comment: Generally you shouldn’t ask duplicate questions – if you want to bump an existing question to the top, offer a bounty. That said, I think this question is much superior and has a higher chance of being answered so I hope that people take this into consideration before voting to close.

Comment: I don't think such thing is possible via code, it will render the whole block meaningless. You should find where your site is blacklisted and convince them your site is OK.

Comment: ye, this was the logic I was afraid of ;) But its the only thing that makes sense. Ideas on where sites are listed as adult? Other than the carrier that is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst I try to find the different network's system for checking the status of the site i will update this answer will the different carriers.

**02**
For UK network 02 please see here: 
http://urlchecker.o2.co.uk/urlcheck.aspx